# Perforce: How to change the password length requirement?

Tags: passwords, perforce, passwd

I'm looking to change the password of a user in perforce to something that is 7 characters, but I get the message:
Password should be at least 8 characters in length.

I know this can be changed, but I'm not sure how. Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Found the answer to this, you can use "p4 configure set security=0" to temporarily loosed up password requirements, change the password, then set your security back. However, if your security is set to level 2, a password change is required and this technique won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in Perforce can be done by command line, but for the fans of User Interfaces, you can launch `P4Admin`, then use `Administration` and `Password Security Level`. This will open a dialog with 4 options:

- 3 (ticket-based authentication required)
- 2 (strong passwords required)
- 1 (passwords required)
- 0 (passwords not required)

If your current user does not have the rights you will have a pop up warning you.

The `Security Levels` are detailed [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/03_superuser.html#1081537) where the rules are explained. As explained in Smeltdown's comments, level 1 will have "legacy support"

```
Legacy support: Strong passwords are required for users of post-2003.2 Perforce applications, but existing passwords are not reset.
Pre-2003.2 Perforce applications can set passwords with p4 passwd or in the p4 user form, but password strength is not enforced.
Users with passwords can use either their P4PASSWD setting or the p4 login command for ticket-based authentication.
```

For level 2, the support is not as flexible:

```
Legacy support: All unverified strength passwords must be changed.
Users of pre-2003.2 Perforce applications cannot set passwords. Users at release 2003.2 or higher must use p4 passwd and enter their passwords at the prompt. Setting passwords with the p4 user form or the p4 passwd -O oldpass -P newpass command is prohibited.
On Windows, passwords are no longer stored in (or read from) the registry. (Storing P4PASSWD as an environment variable is supported, but passwords set with p4 set P4PASSWD are ignored.)
Users who have set strong passwords with a 2003.2 or higher Perforce application can use either their P4PASSWD setting for password-based authentication, or the p4 login command for ticket-based authentication.
```